# Статическая сборка QT 5.11.1

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, mingw, static

уже все примеры перепробовал, ну никак не получается, у меня есть QT 5.11.1 и Src от него но лежит это все в отдельной папке на диске D[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 и я хочу сделать статическую линковку, я перепробовал все способы, что нашел, и ни один не заработал, помогите

Comment: если интересует могу расписать сборку 5,9,0 с компилятором от студии (опционально с опенссл).

Comment: А Вы пытались гуглить, яндексить и т. п.? практически по любой ссылке qt собирается статически. Уточните в чем проблема? http://g.zeos.in/?q=qt%20static%20build шестая ссылка http://amin-ahmadi.com/2017/11/01/how-to-build-qt-5-9-2-static-using-mingw/

Comment: конечно пытался... постоянно что=то не так, то просто стоит, то пишет, что какие-то проблемы с qt-sqlite, то не видит настройки....